# Is there a more optimal way to concatenate this string

Tags: c#, string

I was wondering if there's a more simple way to concatenate this string instead of declaring a temporary variable

```
string tempValue = "000000000000000" + moneyValue;
 moneyValue= tempValue.Substring((tempValue).Length - 15, 15);
```

I'm looking to a shorter way of achieving same result , is there any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a more succinct way to left-pad a string with zeroes.

.NET has a built-in method for that:

```
moneyValue = moneyValue.PadLeft(15, '0');
```

Comment: I always liked Heinz ketchup , only today I knew why ....thank you Heinzi

Answer (score 1):

`PadLeft` works when you start with a string. If you want to combine zero padding with formatting of a number, you can use [`D15` format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros) for integers

```
int moneyValue = 123456;
string moneyString = $"{moneyValue:D15}";
```

or a custom format for other numeric types

```
decimal moneyValue = 1234.56;
string moneyString = $"{moneyValue:000000000000000}";
```

Comment: @napi15: Yes. `$"..."` is an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) (available in C# 6 and later).